# Splitting the ports tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports) isn't very big yet, but it's used for very different things. I propose to ban it (because it's too tempting for several different communities) and force the use of more specific tags:

- BSD ports (packages) → [bsd-ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsd-ports)
- Communication ports such as serial ports → [serial-port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial-port) or the like
- TCP (and UDP) ports → [tcp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcp)? [tcp-port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcp-port)? [tcpip-port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcpip-port)?

Comment: This proposal makes good sense to me. No-one would be put at a disadvantage by banning this tag (except perhaps the time commitment required of the re-taggers).

Comment: Follow up: [Please rename /ports to /bsd-ports, and what to do about /ports?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/997)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retagged: [`tcp`+`port-forwarding`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/vnc-over-ssh-port-assignment), [`tcp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/determining-what-process-is-bound-to-a-port), [`tcp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/linux-allowing-an-user-to-listen-to-a-port-below-1024), [`tcp`+`port-forwarding`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/simple-way-to-create-a-tunnel-from-one-local-port-to-another), and [`serial-port`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/linux-serial-port-problem). [This one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/linux-interface-control-3-5-mm-headphone-or-microphone-port) is just off-topic (it's purely about hardware), possibly material for [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

The remaining 9 [ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports) questions are about BSD ports. In the absence of a tag renaming feature, I suppose we can leave it at that.