# Please rename /ports to /bsd-ports, and what to do about /ports?

Tags: support, tags

This is a follow-up to [Splitting the ports tag](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/604/splitting-the-ports-tag)

Today I found that out of 24 questions tagged [ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports), there were:

- 12 about FreeBSD ports
- 10 about TCP or UDP ports
- one about GPIO ports
- one about a port of non-unix software

Since moderators *can* rename tags, please rename [ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports) to [bsd-ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsd-ports), to avoid confusion. Please copy the tag wiki.

I retagged the TCP/IP ports questions to [ip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip), [tcp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcp) or [udp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/udp) as appropriate, but maybe we should have a [ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports) tag. Perhaps a synonym of [tcp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcp), as UDP is a rare case? Or a [tcpip-ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcpip-ports)? Or [tcp-ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcp-ports) and [udp-ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/udp-ports) as synonyms of [tcp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcp) and [udp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/udp)? Should we ban [ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports)?

---

Revising a year later, I retagged 12 [ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports) questions to [tcp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcp). The TCP ports meaning seems to be gaining a little over the BSD meaning, which shows that [ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports) shouldn't be about BSD ports. I still haven't seen a real point to [tcpip-ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcpip-ports) as a separate tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what to do about questions about ports in the networking sense, but I did the [ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ports) → [bsd-ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsd-ports) rename